# Unable to search a text in generated PDF from word

Tags: c#, pdf

We are generating PDF from a WORD document, we are using "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application" our code. The problem is when we open generated PDF and search for a text , it is saying not found though that text is there. I am thinking the content inside PDF is coming as image instead of text, other things like displaying tables, images are coming very good. is there a way to make the PDF searchable?

I am attaching my code also here. Please look into that let me know your thoughts. Your help is appreciated.

Thanks
Sri

CODE:

﻿

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
namespace DocToPdfConverter
{

    public class DocToPdfConverter
    {

        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            String inputFileName = args[0];
            String outputFileName = args[1];
            Console.WriteLine("Started Converting Word Document To Pdf >> .....");
            DocToPdfConverter dc = new DocToPdfConverter();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            dc.ConvertToPdf(inputFileName, outputFileName, application);
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully Done With PDF Conversion.");
            return 0;
        }

        public void ConvertToPdf(String inputFileName, String outputFileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application)
        {
            object originalFormat = null;
            object routeDocument = false;
            object saveOption = null;
            Word.Bookmarks bookmarks = null;
            string bookmarkNames = string.Empty;
            String outName = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                object readOnly = false;
                object isVisible = true;
                object inputsFileName = inputFileName;
                application.Visible = true;
                application.DefaultWebOptions().AlwaysSaveInDefaultEncoding = true;
                Word.Document aDoc = application.Documents.Open(ref inputsFileName, ref missing,
                ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible);
                saveOption = Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
                originalFormat = Word.WdOriginalFormat.wdOriginalDocumentFormat;
                object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;
                object outputFileNames = outputFileName;


                if (aDoc != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Before Export.......");
                aDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat(  outputFileName, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF, false,
                                                 WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForPrint,
                                                 WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument, 0, 0,
                                                 WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent, true, true,
                                                 WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks, true, true, false,
                                                 ref missing);
                Console.WriteLine("After Export..............");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                application.Quit(ref saveOption, ref originalFormat, ref routeDocument);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use another PDF generator.

Comment: Can you select some text with the mouse? If you can select some words, then it is text.

Comment: Hi , I tried to select some text but it is not selecting , so it is not a text. Before moving to another PDF generator, is it possible to modify this code to get that feature.

Comment: Hi Dimitar, can you suggest good doc to pdf converter which we can use in  our code.